# Bash: Loop over an associative array with list as values

Tags: bash

I am a newbie with Bash. I am trying to loop over the following array -

```
declare -A X=(
  ['s1']="firstname"
  ['s1'] "secondname"
  ['s2']="surname"
  ['s3']="other"
)

for arg in "${!X[@]}"; do

  echo "${arg}, ${X[${arg}]}"

done
```

However, I realized that since the key `s1` is repeated, only one of the values will be printed. Therefore I did this -

```
declare -A X=(
  ['s1']="firstname" "secondname"
  ['s2']="surname"
  ['s3']="other"
)
```

However, I don't know how to loop over it.

The output I am looking for is -

```
s1, firstname
s1, secondname
s2, surname
s3, other
```

Please let me know if any clarification is required.

Comment: You can't have duplicate keys in an associative array. And bash doesn't have 2-dimensional arrays.

Comment: Use a real programming language if you need better data structures.

Comment: Maybe you could use space-separated values, e.g. `['s1']="firstname secondname"`

Comment: @Barmar Sure. I could do that. Anything that solves the problem :)

Comment: @Barmar Would I be able to use a for loop in Bash, if I used   `['s1']="firstname secondname"`

Comment: Try: `declare -A X='()';X['s1']+="firstname " X['s1']+="secondname " X['s2']+="surname " X['s3']+="other ";declare -p X` then `printf '<%s>\n' "${X[@]% }"` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bash` doesn't have 2-dimensional arrays. You coul use space-separated values and nested loops.

```
declare -A X=(
  ['s1']="firstname secondname"
  ['s2']="surname"
  ['s3']="other"
)

for arg in "${!X[@]}"; do
    for val in ${X[${arg}]}; do
        echo "${arg}, ${val}"
    done
done
```

Note that this comes with some caveats:

- It won't work if the nested values can contain whitespace (although you could use a different delimiter that doesn't appear in the values).
- The values shouldn't contain wildcard characters, since filename expansion occurs when the value is substituted. We can't quote `${X[${arg}]}` because that would prevent word splitting.

Comment: Thank you for this. Why didn't you put a `!` in `for val in ${X[${arg}]}`, whereas this `for arg in "${!X[@]}"; do` had it.

Comment: The `!` is used to get the array keys. The inner loop isn't processing an array, it's processing a string.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a set of entities (people?) with attributes for each entity (forename, surname, etc.) your array should really look like

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -A X
X['s1']='Joe,,Blow,Capricorn'
X['s2']='Ann,Flan,Smith,Aquarius'

for id in "${!X[@]}"; do
    IFS=',' read -r firstname secondname surname other <<<"${X[$id]}"
    printf 'id: %s\n' "$id"
    printf '\tfirstname: %s\n' "$firstname"
    printf '\tsecondname: %s\n' "$secondname"
    printf '\tsurname: %s\n' "$surname"
    printf '\tother: %s\n' "$other"
done
```

```
$ ./tst.sh
id: s1
        firstname: Joe
        secondname:
        surname: Blow
        other: Capricorn
id: s2
        firstname: Ann
        secondname: Flan
        surname: Smith
        other: Aquarius
```

Choose whatever separator you like for the attributes if you don't want to use `,`.